# React component doesn't re-render after the state was updated

Tags: reactjs, forms, state, rerender

I am having an issue with the React class component. This component is a form that stores the input of a user and submits the collected information to the main component when the button is clicked. The issue occurs when, after pushing the state up, I am trying to update the state of the component to have the default input values(this.setState(this.baseState) in submitForm).
I am using react chrome extension and can see that the state was updated by can't see it rendered on the page.
[img1:before calling submitForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwEcO.png)
[img2:after calling submitForm, state is updated but can't see changes on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRwro.png)

Would appreciate your thoughts on this!

```
class AttendeeForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      shirt: 'XS', // default
      skillLevel: 'beginner', // default
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  submitForm() {
    this.props.addAttendee(this.state);
    this.setState({
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      shirt: 'XS', // default
      skillLevel: 'beginner', // default
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="attendee-form">
        <h2>Register Attendee</h2>
        <label>First Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
        <label>Last Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="lastName" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
        <label>Email: </label>
        <input type="email" id="email" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
        <label>Shirt Size:</label>
        <select onChange={this.handleChange} id="shirt" >
          <option value="XS">XS</option>
          <option value="S">S</option>
          <option value="M">M</option>
          <option value="L">L</option>
          <option value="XL">XL</option>
          <option value="XXL">XXL</option>
        </select>
        <label>Skill Level:</label>
        <select onChange={this.handleChange} id="skillLevel" >
          <option value="beginner">beginner</option>
          <option value="intermediate">intermediate</option>
          <option value="expert">expert</option>
        </select>
        <button onClick={this.submitForm}>REGISTER</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: simply give value to all input fields and it clears on submit

Answer (score 0):

give default values to all input fields

```
<input type="text" id="lastName" value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

Every field need the current value from the state,
in example firstName and lastName is from the state

```js
class AttendeeForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      shirt: 'XS', // default
      skillLevel: 'beginner', // default
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  submitForm() {
    this.setState({
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      shirt: 'XS', // default
      skillLevel: 'beginner', // default
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="attendee-form">
        <h2>Register Attendee</h2>
        <label>First Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.firstName}></input>
        <label>Last Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="lastName" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.lastName}></input>
        <label>Email: </label>
        <input type="email" id="email" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
        <label>Shirt Size:</label>
        <select onChange={this.handleChange} id="shirt" >
          <option value="XS">XS</option>
          <option value="S">S</option>
          <option value="M">M</option>
          <option value="L">L</option>
          <option value="XL">XL</option>
          <option value="XXL">XXL</option>
        </select>
        <label>Skill Level:</label>
        <select onChange={this.handleChange} id="skillLevel" >
          <option value="beginner">beginner</option>
          <option value="intermediate">intermediate</option>
          <option value="expert">expert</option>
        </select>
        <button onClick={this.submitForm}>REGISTER</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <AttendeeForm  />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```